# Deleting and creating a new workbook with the same name

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I would like to create a new Workbook with the name 'Land-DE'. If the file already exists in the directory it must delete it automatically before creating a new one. I've tried using the following code but it is not working.

```
Sub createwb()
    Workbooks.add
    Dim FSO
    Dim path As String
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set path = "D:\Job\Land-DE.xlsx"
    If FSO.FileExists(path) Then
        FSO.DeleteFile path, True
    else
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "D:\Job\Land-DE.xlsX"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're saving the file in the `Else` branch. That means that if a file with that name exists you'll delete it but not replace it.

Comment: You're also using `Set` to define a string. `Set` is only used for Objects (i.e. Ranges etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the following. This will check if there is a file with the name defined in `path` and if so delete it before saving it again.

```
Sub Createwb()
    Dim path As String

    path = "D:\Job\Land-DE.xlsx"

    If Dir(path) <> "" Then Kill path

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs path
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Why must it be deleted before save? Would it be enough:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "D:\Job\Land-DE.xlsx"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub createwb()
    Workbooks.Add
    Dim FSO
    Dim path As String
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    path = "D:\Job\Land-DE.xlsx"
    If FSO.FileExists(path) Then
        FSO.DeleteFile path, True
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs path
End Sub
```

Two things: `Set` is used for setting objects. The path there is just a string variable. Objects are a group of functions and variables, like that FSO object you create above it.

Next, you need to make sure you save after you delete it, and also that the last version of the save is not still open when you loop through again. If it is, you'll get permission denied for trying to save over a file that's currently open.

Comment: Whilst your code would work correctly. There is no reason to do the `SaveAs` inside the `If` block. Writing it in such a way makes longer code difficult to maintain as you're having to do two changes for the same thing (which can be easily missed). When you have something which happens in all statements of the `If` block it is much better to execute them outside.

Comment: True, and fixed. I was a bit careless in making this run. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code

```
set path = "D:\Job\Land-DE.xlsx" 'It is syntax error, you can only set object in VBA , string is not considered as object

FSO.DeleteFile path, True 'USE kill instead, better performance
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "D:\Job\Land-DE.xlsX" ' Do not user active keyword, always set the object
```

Here is the code :

```
Sub createwb()

    Dim wbnew As Workbook
    Set wbnew = Workbooks.Add

    Dim path As String
    path = "D:\Job\Land-DE.xlsx"

    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            If FSO.FileExists(path) Then
            On Error Resume Next
                Workbooks("Land-DE").Close False ' Close the workbook if open
            Kill path
            wbnew.SaveAs path
    Else
        wbnew.SaveAs path
    End If
End Sub
```